# How can I create a library with a test app in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I would like to create a library project in Android Studio along with a test app for it.

1. The library needs to build to a .jar file that will be reused in other android projects.
2. The test app is an android app that uses the library. It will have android activities and unit tests.

I would like to have both 1. and 2. in a single Android Studio project.

I did that in Eclipse, but would like to migrate the project to Android Studio. Is there an easy way to do it in Android Studio currently?

I tried to read the [Gradle plugin documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) but found it incomprehensible.